# Using ContentBuilder.js with .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to integrate contentbuilder.js into a .NET MVC application.

I can get the page to load, but I am stuck on how to extract the edited HTML in order to save it.

Innova does not seem to offer any demos on integration. Any insights would be most helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out. Posting for anyone else that use ContentBuilder, c# and MVC.

The model receiving the data need to have the [AllowHtml] attribute:

```
    public class HtmlModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [AllowHtml]
        public string Html { get; set; }
    }
```

The submit javascript needs to go between the jquery and validate -- you can use the tag below in your layout page to allow script content on the view page to be placed there.

```
 @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

The HTML page:

```
@model MVCTutorial.Models.EmployeeViewModel

@section Scripts
    {
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {

                debugger

                var builder = new ContentBuilder({
                    container: '.container',
                });

                var html = builder.html(document.querySelector('#cmshtml')); //Get 1st area content

                var data = $("#myForm").serialize() + '&Html=' + builder.html(document.querySelector('#cmshtml'));

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/HtmlHelper/Index",
                    data: data,
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("you are done");
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    </script>

}

<div class="container" style="width:40%; margin-top:2%">

    <div id="cmshtml">
        <p>hello world!</p>
    </div>

    <form id="myForm">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PageName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "name" })
        <input type="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary " id="btnSubmit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

The controller (simplified)

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(CMSmodel model)
        {
                string html = model.Html;
                string Name = model.Name;

///perform tasks here

return View();
}
```